# Spring Social credentials Facebook sign in

Tags: spring, spring-social

I've been 2 days trying to understand how does Spring social works. I don't have a high Spring knowledge so i might be asking something really stupid , sorry in thath case :P. The thing is that the [example](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-facebook/tree/master/complete/src/main) provided by Spring works prefect, but when i try to do exactly the same on other project, when i try to access to /connect/facebook the browser ask me for a username and password, i dont know why.

Thanks you for your time! :P

Answer (score 0):

Hehe, i think i finally found out the problem. I was importing Spring security dependencies and some other that i didn't need.